# Xcode "Do not submit apps with GCC-style coverage" iOS upload processing error

Tags: ios, xcode, gcc

This only happens post app store upload and during processing.

Relevant settings for all targets:

`CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE = NO`
`GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS = NO`

[image]
[image]
Can someone point to a config setting that could resolve this *very* recent issue with Xcode Version 7.2 (7C68)? Uploads have been fine until this point and no related config changes have been made.

The specific error:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "*The App Name*". To process your delivery, the following issues must
>   be corrected:
>
> Invalid Bundle - Do not submit apps with GCC-style coverage
>   instrumentation enabled. Specifically, the following Xcode build
>   settings should be disabled: Instrument Program Flow Generate Test
>   Coverage Files
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Comment: What are the build settings for "Generate Test Coverage Files" and "Generate Profiling Code"?

Comment: "Generate Test Coverage Files" does not exist, only "Generate Legacy Test Coverage Files" set to NO.

Comment: "Generate Profiling Code" is set to NO.

Comment: Sounds like a problem on their end. Maybe use a Technical Support Incident if you're not getting anywhere.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Comment: We started receiving emails about this again for an app that was Waiting for Review and I wasn't able to figure it out, but then this morning Apple moved the app to In Review.

Comment: The existing answers helped point me in the right directions with this technical Q&A rounding out the info https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1964/_index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work around this issue I set "Enable Bitcode" to "No" at the project level, which was it was previously set to and the last known good setting.

Comment: Note that the recommended setting for this is is YES.

> Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and linked on the store. Including bitcode will allow Apple to re-optimize your app binary in the future without the need to submit a new version of your app to the store.
https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two relevant settings which should be `NO` for the **Release** configuration:

`GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES = NO;`
and
`GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS = NO;`

Or in Xcode, under Build Settings > Apple LLVM 7.0 - Code Generation

[image: Xcode Settings]

I found that the *Enable Code Coverage Support* (`CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE`) is **not** required to be disabled. Vanilla Xcode projects have this enabled by default.

Also, of course you only need to make sure that the GGC settings are disabled for the **Release** configuration, assuming that's used for *Archive*.

---

#### 3rd party frameworks

Finally note that if your project includes any 3rd party frameworks, all of these frameworks also need to be build using the above settings.

Unfortunately Apple iTunes Store's email doesn't tell you which project or framework failed, so debugging this might involve some trial and error.

Comment: Interesting. I did try both the `GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES = NO;` and `GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS = NO;`, but I did not check them for the 3rd party frameworks. Changing those settings represents other challenges so I may need to stick to the `Enable Bitcode` approach for now.